# can you release parts of a website in TFS?

Tags: tfs, build, release

My team uses TFS for source control.  I recently created a build and a release that we use to push changes to the website to other environments.  All work is done in cloud and then released to DEV so that the analysts can verify it works as needed before moving on to UAT and PROD.

If the other programmer and I both check-in files to DEV for the analysts to take a look at BUT one is approved and the other changes are not is there a way to release only the changes that get approved?

Comment: Hi  gbgordy, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use approvals to achieve your requirement in TFS/Azure DevOps Server.

> When a release is created from a release pipeline that defines
>   approvals, the deployment stops at each point where approval is
>   required until the specified approver grants approval or rejects the
>   release (or re-assigns the approval to another user). You can enable
>   manual deployment approvals for each stage in a release pipeline.
>
> For example, a **manual approval check** on an environment would
>   ensure that deployment to that environment only happens after the
>   designated user(s) has reviewed the changes being deployed.

In your case, if you have set up a complete CI-CD pipeline in TFS. Other programmer and you both check-in files to DEV.

First use pull request which let your team review code and give feedback on changes before merging it into the dev branch. This is the first step to verify some code changes are qualified.

Then use a build pipeline to build your source project, you could set up a CI build. It will generate a build for each commit. The build will generate some build artifacts.

Use a release pipeline with some approver to deploy your generated build artifacts to your test environment, product environment.  If some stage get rejected, the deploy will fail and no changes released on that environment.

Even though other programmer and you both check-in files to DEV branch, it will trigger different build and different release.

Finally, you could also set up some approval notifications, an email message can be sent to the approver(s) defined for each approval step.

[image]

More details please refer our official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/approvals?view=azure-devops).